# The regular desktop is on tty7 but when i startx it goes on tty8

Tags: lubuntu

When I login to Lubuntu the desktop boots normally but when I do startx from boot terminal the desktop boots but my sound isn't working and it sames to be in a different desktop session. The regular desktop is on tty7 but when I startx it goes on tty8. When switch to tty7 it shows the default desktop but tty8 has a broken desktop.

Comment: Are you trying to get back to Gui, if so try chvt 7 instead of startx.

Comment: Hi i get an error it says this:  Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console

Comment: How exactly do you get to the boot terminal?

Comment: I change splash to text in /etc/default/grub

Answer (score 0):

Yes your GUI is on TTY7, if you give the command startx Ubuntu starts a new graphics session, on the next available TTY, and thats TTY8, unfortunately some of the hardware (sound device) are already in use on TTY7, and the sounddevice is may not be avaliable in TTY8. Your browsers will try to continue - opening new tabs!!
To get back to your TTY7 (the GUI) type: chvt 7 and press enter, or use [Ctrl] [Alt] [F7].
If you really wants to start another Gui-session, you need to logon with another acount in TTY1 (or 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), Linux Ubuntu have 6 main TTY terminals.
All your local settings are in your Home-folder, by giving an orher login name, the other Home-folders settings are used, hence no conflicts.